# What are the Analytic subsets of the Cantor space $\{0,1\}^{\mathbb N}$

Tags: general-topology, terminology, descriptive-set-theory, cantor-set

I'm trying to understand this concept of **Analytic subset of Cantor Space** that is, which subsets of the Cantor Space are **Analytic subsets** and how to determine that.

Here is what I've known this far (from **Wikipedia**):

**[Polish Space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polish_space):** A topological space that is separable and completely metrizable i.e. a separable space which can be induced by a complete metric.

**[Analytic Subsets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_set):** A subset of a Polish space is analytic if it is continuous image of a Polish space. These subsets are closed under *countable union and intersection*, *continuous image*, *inverse image. *(This is not getting conceptually clear to me - ***subsets of Polish space that are continuous images of Other Polish spaces? Too complicated !***)

Now the Cantor space is denoted by $C=\{0,1\}^{\mathbb N}.$ Now, to find out the **analytic subsets** of $C$, I need to know first whether $C$ itself is *Polish* or not, right? If the **Cantor space** itself is separable and be induced by a complete metric. But are those true? I know an *uncountable separable completely metrizable space* has the Cantor Space as a subspace. But if $C$ is not $Polish$ itself, then how will that given definition of *analytic  subsets* work here? (According to **Wikipedia**, only Polish spaces can have Analytic subsets; correct me if I'm wrong.)

A subset of $C$ here consists of a family of infinite binary sequences. How do I decide when this subset is **Analytic**?

It is because of [Some further results on ideal convergence in topological spaces](http://ac.els-cdn.com/S0166864112001812/1-s2.0-S0166864112001812-main.pdf?_tid=d65cd44e-9c84-11e6-ac84-00000aacb360&acdnat=1477600682_b64d87353fbe6995d1ead4df36ad81e2) by Pratulananda Das where **Analytic P ideals of $\mathbb N$** are  used but I do not know how those things look. I realize that this should have been my first post concerning this paper. Anyways, kindly help me to understand this concept. Hope I've conveyed my query properly. Thanks.

Comment: Re: *I do not know how analytic P-ideals look like.* In Das' paper you find a result of Solecki, which says that analytic P-ideals are precisely the ideals of the form $$\mathcal I=\operatorname{Exh}(\phi)=\{A\subseteq\omega; \|A\|_\phi = 0\}$$
where $$\|A\|_\phi=\limsup_{n\to\infty} \phi(A\setminus n)=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \phi(A\setminus n).$$ and $\phi$ a lower semicontinuous submeasure. Probably you could learn more about this type of ideals from the relevant chapters of the I. Farah. *Analytic Quotients* and V. Kanovei: *Borel Equivalence Relations.*

Comment: Or at least by skimming through those chapters, you should see several examples of various classes of analytic ideals. (I should add that this is not a topic I am too familiar with, but I've stumbled upon it a few times.) Also, every Borel set is analytic, so if you can show that some ideal is, for example, $F_\sigma$ of $F_{\sigma\delta}$, then you know that it is analytic.

Answer (score 1):

The Cantor space is indeed a Polish space; consider the metric given by $d(f, g)=0$ if $f=g$ and $d(f, g)=2^{-n}$ if $n$ is the least natural number such that $f(n)\not=g(n)$. Alternatively, view the Cantor space as a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ (the [Cantor set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_set)) and use the induced metric. It's a good exercise to show that each of these metrics is compatible with the topology, and is complete.

Meanwhile, you state that you find the definition of an analytic set to be too complicated. This is, unfortunately, the nature of the beast: analytic sets are quite complicated objects! We may improve things a little by the following: an analytic subset of a Polish space $X$ is a continuous image of [the **Baire space**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baire_space_(set_theory)) $\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}$ (this is also a Polish space; in fact, the first metric I described above for the Cantor space works here). This is simply because *every* Polish space is the continuous image of Baire space (this is a good exercise). However, this doesn't make things much simpler. Analytic sets are pretty complicated objects: every Borel set is analytic, for example.

The following is a good exercise for getting a handle on how analytic sets behave:

> Consider $\mathbb{R}$ with the usual topology; this is a Polish space. Show that $[0, 1], (0, 1), \mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$, and $\mathbb{Q}$ are all analytic subsets of $\mathbb{R}$.

Where things get really fun is beyond the Borel. We can view an element of Cantor space $f$ as coding a binary relation $R_f$ on $\mathbb{N}$: we define $R_f$ by saying $R_f(a, b)$ holds iff $f(\langle a, b\rangle)=1$, where "$\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$" is some bijection from $\mathbb{N}^2$ to $\mathbb{N}$ (e.g. [the Cantor pairing function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing_function)). Now, for $\mathfrak{P}$ some property of relations on $\mathbb{N}$, let $S_\mathfrak{P}$ be the set of $f\in 2^\mathbb{N}$ such that $R_f$ has property $\mathfrak{P}$ (e.g. if $\mathfrak{P}$ is "holds for infinitely many pairs," then $S_\mathfrak{P}$ is the set of all $f\in 2^\mathbb{N}$ which have infinitely many $1$s). Then if we let $\mathfrak{Q}$ be the property, "Is not a [well-ordering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-order) of $\mathbb{N}$," it turns out that $S_\mathfrak{Q}$ is analytic but not Borel. Indeed, $S_\mathfrak{Q}$ is in some sense *the most complicated* analytic set! See Kechris' book on descriptive set theory for more details; he does a good job of describing the basic properties of analytic sets.

Comment: what are $f$ and $g\ ?$ Seems like they are functions from the Cantor's space to somewhere. To where exactly?

Comment: @user118494 No, $f$ and $g$ are *elements* of the Cantor space. But elements of the Cantor space are functions from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\{0, 1\}$!

Comment: Since you wrote $f(n)\neq g(n)$  so I thought they must be functions!

Comment: @user118494 *They are* - elements of Cantor space are functions! A *point* in Cantor space is a *function* from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\{0, 1\}$.

Comment: But in your last comment you said *no*! Ok, I get it. Functions from $\mathbb N$,  not from the *Cantor's Set* itself .

Comment: @user118494 Yes. They are functions, just not from Cantor space.

Comment: Oh! Is it that thing $\{0,1\}^{\mathbb N}\ ?$ This is the function that identifies the Cantor Space with $P(\mathbb N)$.

Comment: Yes, in general "$A^B$" denotes the set of functions from $B$ to $A$. You can think of the Cantor space as either $\{0, 1\}^\mathbb{N}$ or as $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$; the two interpretations are related via the notion of the [characteristic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function) of a set.

Comment: Cantor Space is separable.It is uncountable itself. Is the countable dense subset $\{e_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ where $e_i$  is the infinite binary sequence haveng only $1$ at i-th place and $0$ elsewhere?

Comment: @user118494 No, that set is not dense - for instance, the set $U=\{f: f(0)=1, f(1)=1\}$ is open in Cantor space but no $e_i$ is in $U$ since any element of $U$ has at least two $1$s.

Comment: Ok. Guess I've to read some more to find out that set. Thank you.